# Wordpress woocommerce - hide other shipping method when flat rate available

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It's easy to find how to hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available. But I would like to hide other shipping methods when **flat rate** is available (I have custom other methods).

Can you help please ?

regards

Answer (score 2):

The code below is modified from [this article](http://www.xadapter.com/2016/06/15/woocommerce-2-6-hide-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/) :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'xa_hide_shipping_rates_when_flat_rate_is_available', 10, 2);
function xa_hide_shipping_rates_when_flat_rate_is_available($rates, $package) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $version = "2.6";
    if (version_compare($woocommerce->version, $version, ">=")) {
        foreach($rates as $key => $value) {
            $key_part = explode(":", $key);
            $method_title = $key_part[0];
            if ('flat_rate' == $method_title) {
                $flat_rate_shipping = $rates[$key];
                // Unset all rates.
                $rates = array();
                // Restore flat rate shipping rate.
                $rates[$key] = $flat_rate_shipping;
                return $rates;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (isset($rates['flat_rate'])) {
            // Below code is for unsetting single shipping method/option.
            $flat_rate = $rates['flat_rate'];
            // Unset all rates.
            $rates = array();
            // Restore flat rate shipping rate.
            $rates['flat_rate'] = $flat_rate;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

I am not sure which WooCommerce version you are using but I have tested for version 2.6 but not the versions before it.

Comment: Damned. I never came and didn't saw any alert for your answer. I'm very sorry, and many thanks for your help. I finally managed had to manage my shipping methods differently for this project.
Regards